# HQL is unable to understand a class's property which is a set of another class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am having two classes, say `A` and `B`.
`A` has a set of `B` as its property. `B` has no idea about `A`.

```
Class A {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
    private Set<B> bs;
}
```

The problem is, when I want to delete those records of `A` which do not have `B`, HQL does not understand it! My code is like this:

```
String hql = "DELETE FROM A WHERE bs IS NULL";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
query.executeUpdate(); // <-- Here an exception is thrown
```

As it seems, the HQL is unable to understand that this property is not a column, and it has to join to the `A_B_MAPPING`.
I have also noticed that the generated query is referring to this `bs` property
as `non-qualified-property-ref`!

So the question is, how can I modify my query to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you please add to your question the whole stacktrace of the exception when you call `executeUpdate()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HQL, you need to declare an alias to use it as your instance variable and access the fields. Try to modify your query like that:

```
String hql = "DELETE FROM A a WHERE a.bs IS NULL";
```

Another problem with HQL and collections is that maybe, the collection won't be null, but empty. In that case, you should use `is empty` instead of `is null`:

```
String hql = "DELETE FROM A a WHERE a.bs IS EMPTY";
```

I think you need the `is empty` query form to solve your problem.

Comment: What if the set is assigned with `NULL`? can `IS EMPTY` still be applied? Does it work for both conditions?

Comment: You should try, but I think Hibernate always create an empty Set. You shouldn't have a NULL property for `a.bs` reference. So you should use the `is empty` expression in your `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks. Declaring alias did the job.